# How to attempt connection to WiFi only once?

Tags: wifi, nodemcu, rtc, blynk, ntpclient

I am working on a garden timer project, I connect to WiFi once and if its successful show time from NTPClient or else show time from RTC.

I have been done the above, and it works in the sense that if I turn off the WiFi **while the program is running**, it switches to the RTC and back to NTPClient when  WiFi is available again.

**PROBLEM-** If the WiFi is not available **when the board boots**, the program just waits for WiFi where I want it to use RTC.

Hardware-ESP8266 based NodeMCU, I2C RTC, I2C 16x2 LCD.

Software-Blynk

My code:-

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <DS3231.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "DHT.h"
#include "LiquidCrystal_PCF8574.h"

#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
#define DHT_PIN_DATA  12
// LCD definitions
#define LCD_ADDRESS 0x27
#define LCD_ROWS 2
#define LCD_COLUMNS 16
#define SCROLL_DELAY 150
#define BACKLIGHT 25
#define DHTTYPE DHT22

// Auth code and wifi credentials here
char auth[] = "ymri80lFL9_xjZppphf6WIRHtQ1kqEWOt9zBy";
char ssid[] = "Hotspot-82DB";
char pass[] = "qqnbkbbbk";
int autoSch;
int waterNow;
int morTime;
int afterTime;
int postNoon;
int eveTime;
int schTime;
int minStep;
int interval;
int count;
int flag = 0;
int soilHum = A0;
int waterItr;
int checkRun;
int waterItr1;
int oneTime;
bool h12Flag;
bool pmFlag;

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
byte wifi[] = {
  B00001,
  B00001,
  B00101,
  B00101,
  B00101,
  B10101,
  B10101,
  B10101,

};

DHT dht(DHT_PIN_DATA, DHTTYPE);
LiquidCrystal_PCF8574 lcdI2C;
WiFiUDP ntpUDP;
DS3231 Clock;
NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP, "in.pool.ntp.org", 19800, 600000);

BLYNK_CONNECTED() {
  Blynk.syncAll();
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V0)
{
  autoSch = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V1)
{
  morTime = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V2)
{
  afterTime = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V6)
{
  postNoon = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V3)
{
  eveTime = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V10)
{
  waterNow = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V4)
{
  schTime = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V7)
{
  minStep = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();
  dht.begin();
  lcdI2C.begin(LCD_COLUMNS, LCD_ROWS, LCD_ADDRESS, BACKLIGHT);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(15, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(14, LOW);
  digitalWrite(15, LOW);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V8, 0);
  pinMode(0, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);
      timeClient.begin();
  /*
    while ( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {
      delay ( 500 );
      Serial.print ( "." );
    }
  */
  

  Blynk.syncAll();
  lcdI2C.createChar(0, wifi);
}

void loop()
{
  Blynk.run();
  time_run();
  lcd();
  butPress();
  butCheck();
  /*if (waterNow != 1) {
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V10, 0);
    digitalWrite(14, LOW);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V8, minStep * 60);
    }*/
  if (waterNow == 1) {
    if (waterItr < minStep * 60) {
      waterOn();
      waterItr++;
      delay(500);
    }
    else {
      waterOff();
    }

  } else if (autoSch == 0) {
    auto_run1();
    waterItr = 0;
  } else if (autoSch == 1) {
    sch_run2();
    waterItr = 0;
  } else {
    //Blynk.virtualWrite(V10, 0);
    waterItr = 0;
    digitalWrite(14, LOW);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
  }
  Blynk.syncAll();

}

void butPress() {
  if (digitalRead(0) == LOW) {
    delay (100);
    if (flag == 0) {
      flag = 1;
    }
    else if (flag == 1) {
      flag = 0;
      waterItr1 = 0;
      digitalWrite(15, LOW);
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
    }
  }
}

void butCheck() {
  if (flag == 1) {
    digitalWrite(15, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
    lcdI2C.print("Wtr B Now :  ");
    lcdI2C.print(600 - waterItr1);
    if (waterItr1 < 600) {
      waterItr1++;
      delay(500);
    }
    else {
      waterItr1 = 0;
      flag = 0;
      digitalWrite(15, LOW);
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
    }
  }
}


void lcd() {
  if (oneTime == 0){

    oneTime=0;
    }
  //lcdI2C.clear();
  lcdI2C.setCursor(0, 0);

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    timeClient.update();
    lcdI2C.print("T:");
    lcdI2C.print(timeClient.getFormattedTime());
    Clock.setHour(timeClient.getHours());
    Clock.setMinute(timeClient.getMinutes());
    Clock.setSecond(timeClient.getSeconds());
  } else {
lcdI2C.print("R:");
lcdI2C.print(Clock.getHour(h12Flag, pmFlag)); lcdI2C.print(":"); lcdI2C.print(Clock.getMinute()); lcdI2C.print(":"); lcdI2C.print(Clock.getSecond());
  }
  if (autoSch == 0) {
    lcdI2C.setCursor(10, 0);
    lcdI2C.print(" Auto   ");
  } else {
    lcdI2C.print(" Sch   ");
  }

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    lcdI2C.setCursor(15, 0);
    lcdI2C.write(0);
  }

  if (digitalRead(14) == 1) {
    lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
    lcdI2C.print("Wtr Now           ");
  }
  else
  {
    if (int(timeClient.getHours()) < 6 && morTime == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at: 6a ");
    } else if (int(timeClient.getHours()) < 12 && afterTime == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at: 12n ");
    } else if (int(timeClient.getHours()) < 14 && postNoon == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at:14pn ");
    } else if (int(timeClient.getHours()) < 18 && eveTime == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at: 18e ");
    } else if (int(timeClient.getHours()) >= 18 && morTime == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at: 6a ");
    } else if (int(timeClient.getHours()) >= 6 && morTime == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at: 6a ");
    } else if (int(timeClient.getHours()) >= 12 && afterTime == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at: 12a ");
    }   else if (int(timeClient.getHours()) >= 14 && postNoon == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at: 14a ");
    }  else if (int(timeClient.getHours()) >= 18 && eveTime == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at: 18a ");
    } else {
      if (autoSch == 0) {
        lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
        lcdI2C.print("  Switch to Sch  ");
      } else {
        lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
        lcdI2C.print("  Schedule mode ");
      }
    }
  }
}

void waterOn() {
  lcdI2C.setCursor(0, 0);
  digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
  lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
  lcdI2C.print("Wtr Now :");
  lcdI2C.print((minStep * 60)  - waterItr);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V8, (minStep * 60)  - waterItr);
  Blynk.syncAll();
}

void waterOff() {
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V10, 0);
  digitalWrite(14, LOW);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V8, 0);
  waterItr = 0;
  Blynk.syncAll();
}

void sch_run2() {
  if (schTime == 1) {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    checkRun = 1;
    Blynk.syncAll();
  } else if (schTime == 0) {
    checkRun = 0;
    if (checkRun == 0) {
      digitalWrite(14, LOW);
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
      Blynk.syncAll();
    }
  }
}

void time_run() {
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V11, int(timeClient.getHours()));
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V12, int(timeClient.getMinutes()));
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V13, float(dht.readTempC()));
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V14, float(dht.readHumidity()));
}

void auto_run1() {
  if (morTime == 1 && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) > "06:00:00" && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) < "06:20:00") {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    checkRun = 1;
  }
  else if (afterTime == 1 && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) > "12:00:00" && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) < "12:20:00") {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    checkRun = 1;
  }
  else if (postNoon == 1 && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) > "14:00:00" && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) < "14:20:00") {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    checkRun = 1;
  }
  else if (eveTime == 1 && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) > "11:49:00" && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) < "11:50:00") {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    checkRun = 1;
  }
  else  {
    //(String(timeClient.getFormattedTime() == "06:20:00" || "12:20:00" || "14:20:00" || "13:48:00"))
    //waterNowrun();
    checkRun = 0;
    if (checkRun == 0) {
      //Blynk.virtualWrite(V10, 0);
      digitalWrite(14, LOW);
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V8, 0);
      Blynk.syncAll();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Blynk.begin waits for the WiFi connection. is that what you ask? then it has nothing to do with RTC or NTP. is that your real Blynk token? the esp8266 SDK has NTP, don't use NTPClient library on esp8266.

Comment: @juraj No its not the real one, still would like to use NTPClient

Comment: @juraj What's the problem with NTP, ```Blynk.begin waits for the WiFi connection```. How to prevent it?

Comment: your question is all about NTP and RTC, but you ask about WiFi connection. so I don't know what do you ask. Blynk.begin() calls Blynk.config() and then waits for WiFi. you can use Blynk.config only

Comment: @juraj Forget about NTP and RTC, the code does not execute until its connected to wifi, how do I prevent it?

Comment: replace Blynk.begin with Blynk.config(key) and handle the WiFi connection as usual without Blynk

Comment: @Coder9390 For details see the [Blynk docs](http://docs.blynk.cc/#blynk-firmware).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `blynk.begin()` use `WiFi.begin()` and `blynk.config()` to achieve non-blocking code

```
void setup(){
//  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass); don't use this
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  while ( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {
    delay ( 500 );
    Serial.print ( "." );
  }
  Blynk.config(auth);
}
```